# Get Element in HTML Ordered List by Index Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing, html-lists

I looked quite a bit for a solution for this but I surprisingly couldn't find anything. Maybe I just didn't search for the right words. I found a bunch of questions about getting the index by the element, but I need the opposite.

I'm trying to use javascript and jquery get an element in an ordered list by it's index in the list. For example, if I have this list:

```
<ol>
  <li>Zero</li>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

I would like to be able to get the first one (`Zero`) by its index of 0, or the second one (`One`) by its index of 1.

So far I have tried a few things:

1. A simple function based off of the getting the index of an object in a list using the id.

   ```
   elem = list.index(0); //To get the first element, but this is not a thing.
   ```
2. A loop like this:

   ```
   //elem is the element I am currently at.
   //Starting at the last element and going to the first.
   var elem = list.getLastChild(); //But list.getLastChild() is apparently
   //not a thing although it is here ([w3c link][1]).

   //Start at 0 and go to the index
   //(may/may not need the = before num, but I think I do)
   for(var i=0; i<=num; i++){
       //Set elem to it's previous sibling
   elem = elem.getPreviousSibling(); //getPreviousSibling is probably not a thing as
       //well but I couldn't get that far before it broke anyway.
   }

   //Return the element at the index
   return elem;
   ```

So is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You can use **[:eq](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/eq-selector)** selector. Something like this?

```
var $lis = $('ol li');

for(var i=0; i < $lis.length; i++)
{
    alert($('ol li:eq(' + i + ')').text());
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LcBAQ/)**

So, as this is zero indexed. You could do: `$('ol li:eq(0)')` for getting the first element.
You can also use css, `nth-child`, `nth-of-type` selector:

```
  alert($('ol li:nth-child(1)').text()); // This starts with 1 index, non-zero indexed.
```

Comment: This answer gave me what I wanted (the part in the for loop). @TGH's gave me something else. I'm not sure why but it did.

Comment: @maptwo3 WHat do you mean? You are using nth child....? in that case in the loop do a `+1` also need to be careful if you use `nth-child` especially there are different types of siblings. Such cases nth-of-type will come for rescue. But you could always use `:eq`

Comment: I'm really not sure what I mean. I'm pretty new to web development. They gave me different outputs when I printed them. Yours gave me the actual element, and his gave me something else. Yours worked while his didn't (I also did the `+1` part). The `:eq` part worked for me.

Comment: I just tested this on a `div`, and when I printed them the :eq way gave me a `div`, while nth-child gave me `prevObject` (Those are the first words printed anyway).

Comment: @maptwo3 Ok. I would suggest `:eq` but nth child also should work fine in your scenario probably the `i+1` part is not wrapped in parens. http://jsfiddle.net/fpZu4/

Comment: @maptwo3 Thats where `nth-of-type` will help when the elements siblings are of different types. nth-child doesn't care about the type  of the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery:

```
$("ol li:nth-child(1)")
$("ol li:nth-child(n)")
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: It is not zero indexed. It is 1 indexed/

Comment: Yes, just realized. Updated again :-)

Comment: Cool. Take a +1 from me.. :)